# Spring Data Creates Inner Join On OneToMany

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data, hql, kotlin

So I am using spring data, and I'm having an issue trying to get a list back for this hibernate query.

```
interface NewFooWithMetadataDAO : Repository<Foo, Int> {
    @Query("""SELECT NEW com.foo.persistence.sql.po.NewFooWithMetadataPO(
                    b.id,
                    b.accountId,
                    bi.profitCenterSegmentation,
                    b.fooContext
                )
                from
                    Foo b
                    left join b.fooIntent bi
                    left join b.fooContext bc
                where
                    account_id = ?1
                group by
                    b.id
    """)
    fun findByAccountId(accountId: Int): List<NewFooWithMetadataPO>
}
```

This query creates a hibernate query like this.

```
select 
    foo0_.id as col_0_0_, 
    foo0_.account_id as col_1_0_, 
    foo_buc1_.profit_center_segmentation as col_2_0_,
    . as col_3_0_ 
from 
    foo foo0_ 
    left outer join foo_intent foo_buc1_ on foo0_.foo_intent_id=foo_buc1_.id 
    left outer join foo_context_map foocont2_ on foo0_.id=foocont2_.foo_id 
    inner join foo_context_map foocont3_ on foo0_.id=foocont3_.foo_id 
where 
    account_id=? 
group by foo0_.id
```

Which is a bad query.

I have also tried `bc` instead of `b.fooContext` in the HQL, but then I don't get a collection, I get a single FooContextPO.

My Entities are like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
data class Foo(
        @Id
        val id: Int,
        @Column(name= "account_id")
        val accountId: Int,

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "foo_intent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
        val fooIntent: FooIntentPO,


        @OneToMany
        @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
        val fooContext: Collection<FooContextPO>
){
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "foo_intent")
        data class FooIntentPO(
                @Id
                val id: Int,
                @Column(name = "profit_center_segmentation")
                val profitCenterSegmentation: String
        )
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "foo_context_map")
        data class FooContextPO(
                @Id
                val id: Int,
                @Column(name = "foo_id")
                val fooId: Int,
                @OneToOne
                @JoinColumn(name = "context_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
                val context: ContextPO
        )
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "context")
        data class ContextPO (
                @Id
                val id: Int,
                @ManyToOne
                @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
                val foo: Foo,
                @Column(name = "context")
                val context: String
        )

}

data class NewFooWithMetadataPO(
        val id: Int,
        val accountId: Int?,
        val profitCenterSegmentation: String?,
        val context: Collection<Foo.FooContextPO>
)
```

Is there some way for me to get the left join working correctly here without it generating an inner join?

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely getting the inner join due to selecting the mapped property `b.fooContext` in the below

```
SELECT NEW com.foo.persistence.sql.po.NewFooWithMetadataPO(
                    b.id,
                    b.accountId,
                    bi.profitCenterSegmentation,
                    b.fooContext
                )...
```

You're separately outer joining to `FooContextPO` as `bc` so if you want to avoid the inner join, you cannot reference the mapped property `fooContext`. So you'll need to select `bc` instead.

Is the fact you're only getting 1 record back due to the actual underlying data? Does the SQL its generating when you select `bc` instead of `b.fooContext` look incorrect as well? If so... can you share what that sql looks like?